igraph: edge.betweenness.community() output confusion - bridges
I am having some trouble understanding the output of the edge.betweenness.communities() function, particularly the bridges.
I have a network, I run the function on the network, and it provides me the community object output, with one of the elements being "bridges", that in my instance is showing as "int[1:11]" followed by a list of what I assume are the edges acting as bridges between communities in my network.
However, when I try to access the bridges using, for instance, "net_bridges$bridges" it gives me a vector of like 99 numbers.
Are my bridge edges the ones shown in the int[1:11] list, or are they the edges provided when I access them via $bridges?  And why is there a difference in the output?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

If you are not yet familiar with divisive hierarchical clustering, or the Girvan-Newman algorithm that this function implements, you should read up on it (e.g. section V in https://arxiv.org/abs/0906.0612)
bridges contains the IDs of those edges whose removal caused a split. This is not equivalent to the edges which run between different communities.
